# Function getting informations from website

Tags: javascript, function

Lets take a look here: http://www.pepco.pl/sklepy
When you click one particular shop, there appears window with opening hours and address. In site source I can see that there is javascript function. Is it possible to get all those data using javascript function without having to click on every shop? I need this for informational purposes.

Comment: Ask PEPCO to give you a list. Will save you from a lot of headaches and time.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I try. Nothing to do with this informatically? Not possible to create script or something like that?

Comment: Everything is possible, though info like this normally is protected not making you allowed to do that so I would go the "asking way" .. can't read polish but for sure their are a copyright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a shop, there s a Ajax call which request the specific informations. 
Try to use this url for your purposes.

```
var count = 244,
$output = $('#output');
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {    

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.pepco.pl/web/ajax/sites.city.php?param='+i+'&date_format=Y-m-d',
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $output.append($("<div class='item'>"+data+"</div>"));
    })
    .fail(function() {
        $output.append($("<div class='item'>error</div>"));
    });

}
```

Because of crossdomain policy you cant use this from any other page. A curl solution could work

Comment: Thank you very much. I am getting the following error: GET http://www.pepco.pl/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found), any idea to solve this? :)

Comment: try again, did a mistake in the ajax call and forgot the response